# Qt Creator lacks folder/file structure

Tags: qt-creator, file-structure

Qt does not seem to structure files in folders as other IDEs usually do, like netbeans which places header files in a header folder, source files in a source folder and so on. I have seen this been done in Qt, but I have no clue why it doesn't on my computer.

I have looked at the options and as far as I can see there's no option for it.

Is there an option for this which I have missed or is there another solution which may fix my problem?

Any help would be great,
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not actually change the folder structure, but it simulates that Qt keeps header and source files in different folders.

When I first downloaded it had this setting turned of so it looked like a mess, however I figured out a setting that is next to where it says "Projects" (under Build and Debug most likely) and whenever that is clicked I got saw a "simplified tree" settings was clicked and I just unchecked that.

**In short: make sure the simplified tree option is not checked.**

Comment: I can't find the the Simplified Tree option on my QtCreator 4. Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: If you search (ctrl + f) for simplify tree here http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html you should find it. I am not currently using Qt creator at the moment, so forgive me if they have changed it, though if remember it correctly it should be right above your solution (or project) explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is a library, not an IDE. So I assume you are actually talking about Qt Creator.

Creator does not enforce any structure for your files, that is correct. Just create them where you want them:-) I really do not see how that could be a problem.

In C/C++ projects file structures tend to vary way more widely than in Java and other projects. So by enforcing one file structure you are bound to break lots of projects and make it harder to use those with Creator.

Comment: I figured it out, though I will answer it as its own question. Thanks for the help nevertheless :)